# Does anyone use sanitizer in released software?

Tags: sanitization, address-sanitizer, ubsan

Sanitizers, like:

- address sanitizer (ASAN);
- undefined behavior sanitizer (UBSAN)
- etc.

are frequently used during development and testing.

Are these tools used in released software?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your goals. Sanitizer developers [suggest](https://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2016/02/18/4) not to use them for production hardening (i.e. *protecting* against attacks) because instrumentation may enable different types of attacks. On the other hand they do recommend to occasionally run them in real workloads for *detecting* last 1% of bugs in released software (which e.g. only repro under heavy load).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My friend told me, that "integer overflow sanitization" was applied to Google Android component in release (probably he meant media framework). Can it be true?

Comment: @lollol It seems Android indeed [enables UBSan by default](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/06/compiler-based-security-mitigations-in.html) for some media libraries. But note that they made additional changes to platform during UBSan integration (i.e. it wasn't simply about adding `-fsanitize=undefined`).

Comment: Under "additional changes" do you mean sanboxing?